# Contour plotting complex numbers and conjugates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a contour plot in python with complex numbers (i am using matplotlib, pylab).

I am working with sharp bounds on harmonic polynomials, but specifically right now I am trying to plot:

Re(z(bar) - e^(z))= 0
Im(z(bar) - e^z) = 0

and plot them over each other in a contour in order to find their zeros to determine how many solutions there are to the equation z(bar) = e^(z).

Does anyone have experience in contour plotting, specifically with complex numbers?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


x = np.r_[0:10:30j]
y = np.r_[0:10:20j]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X*np.exp(1j*Y) # some arbitrary complex data

def plotit(z, title):
    plt.figure()
    cs = plt.contour(X,Y,z) # contour() accepts complex values
    plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10) # add labels to contours
    plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(title+'.png')

plotit(Z, 'real')
plotit(Z.real, 'explicit real')
plotit(Z.imag, 'imaginary')

plt.show()
```

EDIT: Above is my code, and note that for Z, I need to plot both real and imaginary parts of (x- iy) - e^(x+iy)=0. The current Z that is there is simply arbitrary. It is giving me an error for not having a 2D array when I try to plug mine in.

Comment: When working with complex numbers you have to pull out something real-valued to plot, either the real/imaginary parts, or the absolute value.  For this I imagine you'd want to use the absolute value. Note: this question is too broad - there is plenty of documentation and examples of contours for matplotlib out on the web.

Comment: I am pulling out the real and imaginary plots and trying to plot them separately, however, on the same contour plot in order to find the zeros of the requisite equation.

Comment: That makes this question something of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Your real question is how to plot to contours on top of each other... have you tried that?

Comment: I am currently able to plot my real and imaginary parts, however they show up on separate windows once the program is run

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you are plotting since you didn't post any code, but in general I advise moving away from using pylab or the pyplot interface to matplotlib, using the direct object methods is much more robust and just as simple.  Here is an example of plotting contours of two sets of data on the same plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# making fake data
x = np.linspace(0, 2)
y = np.linspace(0, 2)
c = x[:,np.newaxis] * y
c2 = np.flipud(c)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cont1 = ax.contour(x, y, c, colors='b')
cont2 = ax.contour(x, y, c2, colors='r')
cont1.clabel()
cont2.clabel()
plt.show()
```

For tom10, here is the plot this code produces.  Note that setting `colors` to a single color makes distinguishing the two plots *much* easier.
[image: real and imaginary contour plot]

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly, is there any way you could help me out with plotting my equation and plotting both its real and imaginary parts on the same window?

Comment: Your problem is that you call `plt.figure` *inside* your plotting function. It will make a new figure!  All you need to do to get what you are looking for is to delete that line.  But I would also not use a plotting function that relies on global variables if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: +1: I think this will work, but why not show the resulting plot, it would be so much more compelling.. also for this particular question it would be really useful to see how confusing this looked?

Comment: Thanks.  And that's not nearly as confusing as I thought it would be.  I guess it's fortunate that the numbers aren't overlapping.